# How to convert all prices to whole numbers (woocommerce + wordpress)

Tags: woocommerce, price

I have imported products with "decimal" like 34.25, 34.12, etc.
How can I delete all "decimal parts" from all prices ? or How to convert all prices to whole numbers
P.S. sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

Under General Settings in the WooCommerce Settings screen, you will find options to set your store Currency, Currency position, Decimal separator, and Number of decimals for your store. Here Number of decimals allows you to Choose the number of digits to appear after the decimal separator.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I need NOT to hide decimals, but to DELETE them (or round, convert to whole number)